# Weird display issue with mySQL TEXT datatype

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I am working on a project where a mySQL table has a field whose datatype is TEXT and collation is utf8_general_ci with the table collation (for some unknown reason) set to utf8_unicode_ci.

mysql -V output is "mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.51a, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2"

PHP version is 5.2.

The data in some rows in this field is "[Dan S. Leyrer?]".  If you query the record from the command line it looks fine.  If you view or edit the record in phpMyAdmin it looks fine in Chrome and IE9.  But when the field is displayed in IE9, Chrome, FF etc as part of the output of a PHP script the question mark is displayed as an apostrophe "[Dan S. Leyrer']".  attempted edits in phpMyAdmin in IE9 and Chrome and from mySQL monitor via command line and no change in display was seen.

Admittedly flailing, I tried adding calls to utf8_encode(), utf8_decode(), htmlentities().  No effect.

I tried editing other fields and eventually I discovered that adding a "?" to any field with datatype TEXT displayed this issue in the PHP output but VARCHAR fields with that same utf8_general_ci  collation did not have the issue.

What is going on there?

---

I owe many apologies to everyone who diligently tried to help me with this.

My predecessor had applied some processing to this string in his spaghetti code. I was not aware of it.  I assume it was an effort to deal with UTF8 issues:

```
function scrub_string($input_string) {
    $replace_array = array( "?","\x92","?","\x91" );
    $input_string = str_replace($replace_array,"'",$input_string);  
    $output_string = utf8_encode($input_string);
    return $output_string;
}
```

I am very very sorry for the wasted time... Come to New Orleans and I am buying the beer.

Comment: http://akrabat.com/php/utf8-php-and-mysql/ should give you a few pointers

Comment: BTW, the table collation is only the default for new columns. For conversion and storage only the connection charset and the column collation are of any importance.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently your DB connection charset (set using [SET NAMES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-connection.html)) differs from the charset your browser is expecting (Firefox Page Info -> Encoding).

Try setting both to UTF-8:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8'); // SET NAMES utf8
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: It won't be enough that the calling file has <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  ?

Comment: That should be sufficient, the *Page Info* dialog tells you for sure. Don't forget the SET NAMES, though.

Comment: Added the query and header.  A couple of fields with é in them were affected display-wise but this issue persists.

Comment: Just to be sure: You are adding a question mark to any TEXT field in phpMyAdmin and in PHP it turns into an apostrophe, right?

Comment: FireFox general tab lists encoding as UTF-8; Content-type text/html; charset=utf-8

Comment: if I add a "?" via mysql Monitor (cmd line) or phpMyAdmin to these fields with TEXT datatype it always displays as a "?" when queried by phpMyAdmin or mySQL monitor.  When displayed via my PHP scripts you see an apostrophe.

Comment: I have to go help cook dinner or wife will start throwing children at me... Sorry.  Back later.

Answer (score 1):

The used collation only determines the way the data is stored and processed inside the database, it does not affect the charset that is used to transfer the data to the client. The latter can bet set with [mysql_set_charset](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-set-charset.php). Try setting the connection to the same charset that is used for the generated output document, maybe that helps.

Comment: Added $lnk = mysql_connect($server,$username,$password);  mysql_set_charset('utf8',$lnk);   but no change...

Comment: From same doc page I added mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'", $lnk);    Still no change

Comment: This really seems to be a weird problem. Do you process the strings in any way on the php side before you send them to the browser? Maybe you could strip your whole php-script down to the parts relevant for reading and printing the data, check if this issue persist and add the code to your question.